# What is the use of Bash in the next update for Windows 10?

Tags: bash, windows-10

In the Build conference this last month, Microsoft said that Bash was going to be introduced in to the anniversary version of Windows 10 in July. And I thought to my self, would this be an advantage (because there is Windows 10 IoT core for Raspberry Pi), or are they getting Linux developers to switch to Windows, since Linux main programming language is Bash.

Comment: What has your research effort shown using Google? Questions on SU expect some research effort on your part and should be included in your question. I found the answer in 5 seconds using Google "Bash in Windows"

Comment: "Linux main programming is Bash" Untrue. Its C.

Comment: Okay i was unsure

Comment: From what I've read, it sounds like bash is part of a Linux platform that will go into a contained/virtualized environment, and it might not even be part of Windows 10, but rather something that can be downloaded from the Windows Store (which can be done easily from within Windows 10).  That might not all be right; I await further details to develop as time marches forth.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) is a [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) which provides a command line interface to the operating system as does the [command prompt on Microsoft Windows systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) or PowerShell. Providing support for Bash on Microsoft Windows makes Windows systems more attractive to software developers as a platform on which they can develop software not only for Microsoft Windows systems, but for other operating systems as well. Bash is not only commonly used on Unix and Linux systems, but is also available as a command line interface under OS X via the [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X)) application.

There will also be a set of tools commonly used with the Bash shell, e.g., [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), etc., by system administrators who work on Linux systems making it a more attractive platform to those accustomed to using those tools to administer Unix/Linux systems, though the opportunity it may provide to woo developers away from other platforms is likely a more primary motivation for including Bash support.  For a reference on Microsoft's motivations for providing support for Bash see the [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) article [Why Microsoft needed to make Windows run Linux software](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/04/why-microsoft-needed-to-make-windows-run-linux-software/)

Comment: You have just encouraged the user to ask questions without doing Any research first, prior research is expected here at SU when asking questions.

Comment: I'd also add *historically*, windows has had the option of a POSIX subsystem. This is very similar, just potentially useful